# How to externalize configuration properties of Cassandra in application.conf?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, playframework-2.6

I found that for `Mongodb`, I can add the information about the database in `application.conf`.

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
play.modules.enabled += "module.Module"
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/demodb
```

Is something similar available for `Cassandra` as well? I know that I could mention the database name, port, IP etc. in the code in `Datastax` driver but I couldn't find information about doing the same in `application.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the [Scala Configuration API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaConfig) to externalize properties. As the documentation states, Play relies on Lightbend's [config library](https://github.com/lightbend/config). Thus, simply specify all your details in a `.conf` file by using the [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md) and then retrieve the properties later on in your code.